'screen -ls' command is not displaying the list of screen sessions
I am not able to see the list of screen sessions running using the command screen -ls. Executing this command line yields nothing. Restarting the terminal hasn't helped me to solve the problem. I can begin a new screen but not able to resume it.
How can I solve this issue?

Are you sure you have screen sessions running at all when you run screen -ls? How are you detaching from the screen sessions? Ctrl/A + Ctrl/D?

Yes. The screen sessions are running. To confirm it I ran a new screen session and, yes, I detached it with Ctrl-A + Ctrl-D (I double checked to be sure that I was not terminating the screen by mistake).
However, after detaching it I am not able to find either the new session or the older ones using the screen -ls command. No output is generated and it remains stuck until I kill it.

Actually I meant: while holding down Ctrl, pressing and releasing A and then pressing and releasing D. It's very different from what I wrote, as Ctrl / A + Ctrl / D will send EOF to the shell, terminating it instead of detaching from it. Are you detaching exactly this way? If done correctly screen should say something like "detached".
